Unable to access drive Unable to access "New Volume" Error mounting /dev/sdb3 atNew Volume: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3
[my battery just got a permanent failure after that when I started my laptop again I tried to open my hard drive this message pop up I tried nothing I don't want to loose my data please help][1]

You've provided no specifics as to what Ubuntu product & release you're using, and what file-system should be on that device. Given the battery failure, you may need to perform file-system checks using the correct command for your unstated file-system, after which you'll likely find you return to normal behavior. You can boot & fix using live media if your unstated Ubuntu product isn't booting currently.

A bit more info would be great of what fs etc it is. or post output from
sudo fdisk -l

But i would suggest booting using a Live CD and scanning the file system and trying to repair it from there. (or at least backing up your files)
sudo fsck -f -y /dev/sdb3

After try to mount it to /mnt f.ex.
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt

If that dont work give a bit of more info.
and if its FAT or NTFS fs install dosfsck or ntfsfix if you dont already have it.
